# Add images into email template in Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, image

I´m trying to add `img` into Blade email in Laravel. But when I receive my email, I can´t see my image, but URL is correct. I´m trying to add `img` this way:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/public/images/guiapaladar-qrcode.png') }}" alt="" style="width: 20%;">
```

In Google Console I can see this:

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/-Ay7pcevYLhUaAu4iicFdd-kGPKGB9hXRemwYYmoes8GnA4nN6Qe_FZDKenf_iDgiNpx5Xb1QX7p_2Su5DCOHAb2-UI8gGHkJhK9V6qb4R-B6_QY=s0-d-e1-ft#http://127.0.0.1/guiaPaladar/public/images/guiapaladar-qrcode.png" alt="" style="width:20%" class="CToWUd">
```

but in my email it doesn't show my image.

Thanks for help me

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/guiaPaladar/public/images/guiapaladar-qrcode.png ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending email through localhost then image will not be displayed. But if you are sending it live then use the following code:

```
<img src="{{asset('images/guiapaladar-qrcode.png')}}" alt="" style="width: 20%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With using markdown you can just :

```
![Random text][logo]

[logo]: {{asset('/images/image.png')}} "Logo"
```

#### Or simply :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64_encode(file_get_contents(resource_path('images/image.png')))}}" alt="">
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but if add your second code, result in email is: <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAALiQAAC4kCAYAAACqaH6IAAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAgAElEQVR4nOzYbW7bTLME0K6VcXYmcmejlfXFBWyAD1/ZsRN/SOI5vyRKnJmuIpBYKQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4Ad09qmrImq+WZBUqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8hUgYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4Xd09qmp88yGWH9gDzmz77tmTrJ4wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgN8V+QMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABn0N2jqsYXjXrx0ABPYvuiMWaS6aEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAnl00DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPyE7h5VNf5y